# Add additional paths to VIM on Windows

Tags: windows, vim, path

I want to add additional `$paths` to vim74 under windows. I use `$VIM/vimfiles` and `$VIM/vimfiles/myfunctions` a lot and wanted to add them as paths, i.e. `$VIMFILES`. I had worked out how to do it in Windows but then the machine died before I documented the method and I've forgotten how I did it.

It used to be that I could type `$VIMFILES\bundle\` for example and it would expand, well `$VIMF` and tab.

**EDIT**
To try and clarify I regularly edit files within the `vimfiles` directory under the main vim directory. I type for eg `e: $VI` and hit tab and it shows the options as in the shot below. I had managed to add `vimfiles` and `vimfunc` to something either in the registry or environment settings but have forgotten how to recreate on a new machine

[image: Vim paths]

Any suggestions?

**EDIT 2**
Of course clarifying the question answered it

In Environment Settings add new variables under user variables

[[image: Env[3]]

Then in vim they are available

[image: Vim variables]

Thanks for the request for clarification

Comment: On the Windows 7 system I'm using with Vim 7.4.729, I don't see environment variables `paths` or `VIMFILES`, nor is there a Vim option named `paths`, so I don't understand what you're looking for.

Comment: @Steve - You should add your edit as an answer and accept it. You'd have my vote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Asked to submit as answer. No upvotes required.

To add variables available in vim, and anything else really, as a `$variable`

Open Environment variables

Add the variables under user variables and call the variable name the one you want to use as the `$variable`

[image: Variables]

Then it's available in vim or in windoze as a `% %` variable eg cd `%vimfiles%`

[image: vim variable]

Then in vim they are available